# i am trying to create a simple login app with angularjs using routing but event is not handled

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to create login app using only angularjs,i have used routing of angularjs initially div in which "ng-view" is defined routes to login page .but after entering the username and password when i click button nothing happens i.e event is not handled..
below is code for index page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="mylogin">
<h1>Login Page</h1>
<div ng-view></div>
<script>
    var app=angular.module('mylogin',['ngRoute']);
    app.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            templateUrl:"login.html"
        })
        .when('/dashboard',{
            templateUrl:"dashboard.html"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo:"/"
        });
    });

app.controller("loginctrl",function($scope,$location)
        {
            $scope.submit=function()
            {
                var uname=$scope.username;
                var pwd=$scope.password;
                if($scope.username=='admin' && $scope.password=='admin')
                {
                    $location.path('/dashboard');
                }
            };
        });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

below is code for login page:

```
    <div ng-controller="loginctrl">
<form action="/" id="mylogin">
Username:<input type="text" id="username" ng-model="username"><br>
Password:<input type="password" id="password" ng-model="pasword"><br>
<button type="button" ng-click="submit()">Login</button>    
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: are you seeing any error messages in the console?

Comment: it looks like your event **is being handled**, but you aren't getting the result you expect, due to a typo.

Comment: hey @claies, thanks for replying ,i corrected the typo now its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo in `ng-model` of `password`, so when you are doing `if($scope.username=='admin' && $scope.password=='admin')` inside controller  `$scope.password` happen to be `undefined`

```
ng-model="pasword"
```

should be

```
ng-model="password"
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/9Y3gwfCojY4dT9aO8h3z?p=preview)

Comment: thanks a lot pankaj parkar it is working now, i can't believe i made such a silly mistake.